# Kamailio as dispatcher in front of FreeSwitch

Tags: sip, freeswitch, openser

I'm struggling with Kamailio as a simple dispatcher for FreeSwitch. This is my configuration so far: http://pastebin.com/nBPSpe6S

Connecting an iPhone and an Android makes the calls between them timeout.
Connecting one of the phones and my laptops makes calls between them produce the error "Too many hops".

With all of them I'm able to call in to the Freeswitch, for listening to voicemail, hold music etc.

So I guess it's still NAT problems or similar?

Can anyone spot the error, missing thing or something else that is wrong with the config?

P.S. Adding phones, laptops etc. directly to FreeSwitch, without Kamailio, makes everything works.

Answer (score 2):

"Too many hops" is just that - too many hops. A SIP messages is being routed around in a bad way. In many cases in Kamailio, this is because DNS and Kamailio doesn't have the same view of the world. Kamailio doesn't know which domains it's authoritative for (the alias= configuration parameter) and forwards using DNS. DNS points back to the same Kamailio.
Your configuration lacks both alias= and IP addresses kamailio should listen to. Now, your configuration doesn't really use the alias, so I don't see that problem here. Since you are not showing the dispatcher table it's hard to figure out. I suggest you add a couple of calls to xlog() to see what's going on and figure out why a message is looping around. Good luck!